Clickteam fusion String Parser accents
I'm coding in Clickteam Fusion 2.5 using String Parser to retrieve some data from a .txt. It just so happens that when I use accents it returns gibberish.
For example, União turns into UniÃ£o (but when I manually set the string it doesn't happen). I searched a little for it, and it seems the problem resides on the encoding not being UTF-8 (if I'm not mistaking it all). Any idea on how to remove this limitation? Thanks in advance.
Edit: here's a MWE in a .rar

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

@JosefZ I'm on it
